# running multiple commands in the same shell on server using python

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, fabric, openssh

I want to run multiple commands with same shell.

Executing command of paramiko library is not with same shell.

Commands :

```
Ssh cloud-user@node -i /path/to/bcmt_rsa
Cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Change permitRootLogin yes to no
Restart sshd server
Log to file.
```

I am new in python. I have tried many ways but not working

Comment: Please show us what you've researched, what you've tried, and explain why none of your research or attempts were helpful.

Comment: I have tried cmd = ["ssh cloud-user@nodename","cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config"] for commads in cmd:proc = subprocess. Popen(commands, shell=True) proc. Communicate()

Comment: Why not just make a shell script and run that?

Comment: How to make shell script. Could be please share some ideas

Comment: C'mon, really? It's a batch file. Use Google...

Comment: Batch file not possible. I have to get node from csv file

Answer (score 0):

Not clear questing but i have example lets say you want to edit file then read it
have variable

`command="echo data >> path_to_file/filename.txt"`
`command+="cat path_to_file/filename.txt"`

then execute ssh normal and read the stdout lines ,or you can use && in the command
like `command="echo data >file_path.txt && cat file_path.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to runultiple comand at a time in single sell?I think its not possible.But you can splot your terminal and can run differend comand in didferent partifion of a terminal.For this you can use Terminator,a great bash terminal.

Besides python is a single threded language.So you can not run multiple function same time in a script.Python will exicute function by function